# Pass SVG string from cookie to RaphaelJS

Tags: svg, raphael

I have a cookie, called 'plan' which contains a string value representing a RaphaelJS canvas and some objects within it as SVG.  The exact paths etc may vary, but here's typlically what's being saved to the cookie:

```
<svg height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;"><desc>Created with Raphaël 2.0.1</desc><defs/><path style="" fill="none" stroke="#d9e026" d="M153,74L384,74L384,304L0,304L0,150L153,150L153,74"/><path style="" fill="#333333" stroke="#d9e026" d="M160,160L160,220L220,220A60,60,0,0,0,160,160" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -103, 84)"/><rect x="121.53846153846155" y="158.5" width="76.92307692307692" height="3" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#333333" stroke="#d9e026" style="" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -89, -9)"/><rect x="83.0769230769231" y="156" width="76.92307692307692" height="5" r="0" rx="0" ry="0" fill="#333333" stroke="#d9e026" style="" transform="matrix(0, -1, 1, 0, 223.038, 364.039)"/></svg>
```

Now I need to be able to pass this data into a new raphaeljs object on a new page and add some more paths etc into it.

Can anyone suggest how to do this as I'm struggling to know where to start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a spiffing new function in Raphael 2 which also simplifies these tasks
Paper.add

http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2&q=paper.add

Comment: Ah, thanks Chasbeen.  So there's no need to use that library above at all?  Paper.add will handle all facets of re-instantiating a Raphael instance (including transformations, rotations etc)?

Comment: Actually, although there's a demo on your site of paper.add, I can't seem to see it in the official documentation http://raphaeljs.com/2.0/.  Is it so new (v2.0.1) that it's just not documented yet?

Comment: Dan Click the Raphael link next to Raphael.add The Raphael.add function was added in 2.01 but those links (Off my site next to the demos) always point to the latest documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Looking into this in a lot more detail, it turns out not to be quite so simple.  The SVG code is only available on newer browsers (IE8+) so this approach won't work in IE7 or less.  Handily though, the Raphael object does store the required data to be able to use before it hits the DOM.  There's a very handy plug-in I found to serialize the Raphael data then de-serialize on output.  Although I'm having a few issues with the deserialization part, in theory this should be the solution: https://github.com/jspies/raphael.serialize.

So that plug-in essentially allows me to do this:

```
Raphael canvas > serialized JSON object > String > Cookie > String > serialized JSON object > Raphael canvas.
```

Comment: Actually, that plug-in is a little buggy in raphael 2, but there's a splinter project which handles it much better here: https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.JSON